# Cloning gitlab project repository adding additionaly directory which is not in repository itself

Tags: git, gitlab

I faced with problem that cloning repository from gitlab create additional folder by repository name.

I have django project on server with the following path

```
tutor #project contained folder
|__env #virtualenv created folder
|__tute #project folder itself
   |__manage.py
   |__tute #project settings
```

I created gitlab repository named repository as **tutorize** pushed project to repo

Than on my local machine i created folder to clone gitlab repo to it

```
mkdir tutor #create folder to store project inside it
cd tutor
virtualenv env #create virtualenv
. env/bin/activate #activated it
git init #initiated git 
git clone my_tutorize_repo_url #cloned repo inside tutor folder
```

I got the following folder structure

```
tutor #folder locally created
|__env #virtualenv folder
|__tutorize #folder which is not on my server and i didnt create it localy. Its my project repository name on gitlab
   |__tute #project foldet
      |__manage.py
      |__tute #project settings
```

While i was expecting

```
tutor
|__env
|__tute
   |__manage.py
   |__tute
```

Is it right begaviour or i am doing anything wrong ??

Comment: Everything you need for the Project should be in the repo folder. If you don't want to push smth you can always add it to the `.gitignore` file. (the env stuff in your case)

Comment: But my problem is not with env i configure my .gitignore for dont clone env to repo.Problem with folder which is repository name which created by gitlab itself while i created repo

Answer (score 0):

To clone git repository without cloning repository name you can do it as follow `git clone [repository] [local path]` important note that local directory should be empty